# Compare consequetive pairs of columns for equality across a dataframe in Python

Tags: python

I want to compare pairs of two columns across my dataframe and test them for equality. Here is the code in R:

```
colSums(df[,seq(1,ncol(df),2)]==df[,seq(2,ncol(df),2)])
```

If my data looks like this :

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
hi  hi  hi  ho  hi  ho
ho  ho  ho  ho  ho  hi
```

My code will compare column a with b, c with d and so on, check how many rows are equal and return me the sum as follows. The dataframe im working on has N x 2N dimensions.(Number of columns are even)

```
a  c  e
2  1  0
```

I am unable to replicate this code in Python(forgive my inexperience)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most concise bit of code, but I believe this is fairly readable and would work as desired.

```
def compare_consecutive_cols(lst):
    res = [0 for i in xrange(len(lst[0]) / 2)]
    for i in xrange(len(lst)):
        for j in xrange(0, len(lst[i]), 2):
            if lst[i][j] == lst[i][j+1]:
                res[j / 2] += 1
    return res
```

Function `compare_consecutive_cols()` maintains a result list of length (`N/2`) to return, and traverses the entire data maintaining that list. (i.e. incrementing a value whenever an equal pair is found) It traverses the data in a row-by-row fashion and checks each consecutive pair on a line.

I tested it with the input matrix you provided, and it seems to work with the following input in the following manner. (A is identical to the matrix you provided)

```
A = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
print compare_consecutive_cols(A)
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/ToHkUC) for an example usage.

Comment: I am completely new to coding so forgive me for asking,
I ran the code above and replaced 'list' with my dataframe name
How do I see the results?
Also my dataframe has N x N columns, apoplogies for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: @Aman I added a sample usage and corrected a couple of mistakes in my code. If your data is organized in a list manner(i.e. similar to A) then it should work now.

Comment: @Aman If N can be an odd number you may need to slightly update this code by replacing the expression checked by the if statement at line 5 with **(j + 1 < len(lst[i]) and lst[i][j] == lst[i][j+1])**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have even number of columns but n number of rows. However, this code does not seem to be working on my dataframe. I replaced 'lst' with my dataframe name and ran it. There is no output. When i tried printing 'res' in a seperate cell it says res is not defined.

Comment: I tried print compare_consecutive_cols(df) too it says key error: 0

Comment: @Aman Since you are a beginner to Python, if you are not familiar with the term, a list of lists is a list that contains lists as elements. In my response, the variable A is a list of lists, as you too may observe. If df is in another format, you should let me know so that I can update the code in my response based on that. Can it be, by any chance, a list of dictionaries?

Comment: I used pd.read_table to read a csv file into my df. After that I deleted some columns and re-arranged columns. I did not do any other treatment so I think its a list of lists.

Comment: @Aman try this: compare_consecutive_cols( df.values.tolist() )

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot man! I really admire this community and hope to one day contribute to it. 
As a last question so I can understand the logic of your code, what would change if instead of getting the sum of equal rows I wanted the sum of unequal rows?

Comment: Just have to change the == operator to a != operator, and it would find the unequal numbers. Theogic is simple. It traverses the entire data, row by row. And at each row, it visits the indices 0, 2, 4... (i.e. the left element in each possible pair in that row) and compare it with the element to its immediate right. If they are equal, it increments the relevant number in res indicating the number of equal pairs found for that pair of columns.